# Do we have some wordplay with "tiny" that is the same way we say "easy peasy"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In [this Youtube clip](https://youtu.be/MxLvMCIrC_o?t=117), **at 1:58**, the witch says something like "**It's tiny pity...wind see ...**" or something like that. I couldn't get it.

What did she say?

Do we have some wordplay with "**tiny**" that is the same way we say "**easy peasy**"?

Comment: The witch says ***Itty-bitty, incy=wincy*** - riffing off the well-known nursery rhyme [***Itsy Bitsy Spider** also known as **Incy Wincy Spider***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itsy_Bitsy_Spider). The "reduplicated" forms there simply emphasize ***tiny size***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character in the clip says two things:

- [itty-bitty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/itty%2Dbitty)
- [eensy-weensy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eensy-weensy)

There are many other terms that could be used, for example:

- [teeny-weeny](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teeny-weeny)
- [itsy-bitsy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/itsy-bitsy)

The term for this formation in general is [**reduplication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication), as described in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/191911/130147) to the question *What is the "peasy" in "easy-peasy"?*

Comment: or with tiny:  "teeny-tiny"